# Is a Logistic Regression Classifier equivalent to an SVM with a Linear Kernel?

Tags: regression, machine-learning

Is a linear SVM functionally equivalent to a logistic regression?

Comment: @Momo - That other question is not actually the same, as it refers to linear regression, not a logistic regression classifier.  The OP should edit this question accordingly and leave it posted.

Comment: @jbowman Apologies. Done!